# Is there a hack to installing SharePoint 2013 on Windows 8?

Tags: development, 2013

Apparently SharePoint 2013 is not officially supported on Windows 8 (which does not make sense to me). And, just like  [the Vista hack for WSS 3.0/MOSS 2007](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2008/05/21/how-to-install-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0-sp1-on-vista-x64-x86.aspx) I am looking for a hack to install SharePoint 2013 on my Windows 8 64 bit machine and I don't want to use a VM.

UPDATE:

I do understand using Hyper-V or some kind of virtualization is a cleaner alternative (with cool features such as snapshots and cloning). However, given the recommended hardware requirements, I would not get the best performance on my 8GB machine. And, I understand that it's not officially supported by Microsoft to install SharePoint 2013 on Windows 8, but it does not mean that the fundamental operating system requirements are not met by Windows 8. Therefore I am looking for a hack, a hack that would fake the version check for the installer so I can fully utilize all my memory for SharePoint instead of spinning a VM.

> Hint: API Hooking

Comment: It's not going to work on Windows 8, let alone with only 8GB of RAM. Get a new laptop and use Hyper-V is the best advice that can be given here.

Comment: @GavinB, thank you for the advice. Since it's an SSD I am hoping I will get what I need, and spending money might not be an option for a lot of people, so I am looking into how I can try using API Hooking (perhaps use http://easyhook.codeplex.com/) or some other way to solve my issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now it is possible, but you decide if it's a good idea for you. It is completely unsupported and should just be used for a local development machine.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.disruptivei.com/Blogg/Inl%C3%A4gg/6/Install-SharePoint-2013-on-Windows-7-8-8-1) by me

Comment: YESSSS!!! You know what, I knew only you would fix it anyways.

Comment: Did you do with API Hooking? @jonas

Answer (score 6):

Installing SharePoint 2013 on Windows 8 is simply **NOT** supported

But, instead Windows 8 is the provided with ability to run Hyper-V in the client O/S and hence you can easily install the SharePoint Server 2013.

Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off and check the box next to Hyper-V and install it:

[image]

Comment: unfortunately for some reason, he doesn't want to use vm so that put Hyper-V role out of option... But professionally wise, I'm extremely happy that these kind of standalone installation are not supported anymore.

Comment: that's true, but still an option exist if he wants to use VM in future. The creepy hacks are simply out of questions with new SharePoint version.

Comment: The point is simple SharePoint 2013 will not support installations on client operating systems.

Comment: I didn't want to use a Windows Server 2008/2012 license, and I like the idea of just starting my machine and have my SharePoint environment up and running with no time wasted without the need to spin my Virtual machine (be it Hyper-V or VMware) or worry how many CPU core or memory I need to assign for optimal performance given my limited resources.

Comment: @natdico, like I said in my reply, you can use trial license & even re-arm them. Keep in mind that 2013 is quite resource hungry (for nowadays hardware) so even on a server os you'll have issue if you don't allocate at very least 6gb to it and 12gb is definitively a sweet spot to start doing real world development. Like I said in my reply, I would go for a CloudShare license or Office 365 depending on the kind of app you'll be building.

Comment: Installation of SharePoint 2013 is supported only on Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 or Windows Server 2012. If you want to develop apps for SharePoint for SharePoint 2013 on Windows 7, you can sign up for an Office 365 Developer Site and develop apps remotely.

Comment: SharePoint loves memory for breakfast and hard-disk for dinner, and I would recommend at least 8 GB of RAM to install with 2 processors (2 cores per processor). Though, MS officially has listed quite on high:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx

Answer (score 2):

That probably won't be possible and will never be officially supported. If you don't want to work with VM, what about booting off a VHD file (you'll still need a Windows Server 2008 / 2012 license, although a trial could do the job).

You should also look at Office 365. As developer (and a Windows Live Id is enough !) you can have your own SharePoint in the cloud to test drive its functionalities and develop applications in the cloud.

Finally, well known solutions like Cloudshare are delivering always available environment for a very low price (hard to beat if you have to purchase a MSDN license & adapted hardware rig) so that's another viable alternative to prevent you from trying to do an unsupported  Windows 8 frankenstein SharePoint 2013 installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it onto windows 7/8/8.1 if you really have to with this guide. 
http://www.guideushow.com/sharepoint/install-sharepoint-2013-on-windows-7-8-and-8-1/

But it's not supported by microsoft and should only be used as a last resort becuase if you can't run it in Hyper-v or VMware it's unlikely you'll beable to just on your host.